# Non Repeating Random Integer values within range of previous guessed values

Tags: random, numbers, integer

I am creating random number game for my class where the computer guesses random values within the range set by the user. I am trying to get it to the point where if the user input Higher or Lower, the new values will not disobey the previous values. For example, if the range is between 2-50 and the value I'm thinking of is 20 and the computer guesses 25 and the user input l (for a lower value), the computer will give back 5 and then the user input h (for a higher value) and the computer might print like 30 but 30 isn't within 5-25, so how would I need to modify my code so that it will always output a value within the range of the previous random values?

```
import java.util.*;

public class Assignment3 {
    static int Highernum;
    static int Lowernum;
    static String Response;
    static int High;
    static int Low;
    static int Number;
    static int random;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);
        Random rand = new Random();
        Boolean play = true;        
    while (play) {
        System.out.println("Set the lowest number boundary:");
        Low = console.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Set the highest number boundary:");
        High = console.nextInt();
        System.out.println("So your number is between " + Low + " and " +               
        High);
        Number = number(Low, High);
        System.out.println("Computer: " + Number);
        System.out.println("Is this your number? 
        (H)igher/(L)ower/(C)orrect");           
        Response = console.next();
        Highernum = number(Number, High);
        Lowernum = number(Low, Number);

        while (Response.equalsIgnoreCase("H")) {
                Highernum = number(Number, High);
                Conditioncheck(console, Highernum); 
        while (Response.equalsIgnoreCase("L")) {
                Lowernum = number(Low, Number);
                Conditioncheck(console, Lowernum);
            } if (Response.equalsIgnoreCase("C")) {
                System.out.println("Play again?(Y/N)");
                String Answer = console.next();
                if (Answer.equalsIgnoreCase("N")) {
                    play = false;
                } else {
                    play = true;
                }
            }
        }
        }
    }


public static void Conditioncheck (Scanner console, int random) {       
            System.out.println("Computer: " + random);
            System.out.println("Is this your number? 
            (H)igher/(L)ower/(C)orrect");
            Response = console.next();

    }

public static int number (int Low, int High) {
    Random rand = new Random();
    int randomNum = rand.nextInt((High - Low) + 1) + Low;
    return randomNum;
}


public static Boolean check (Scanner console, Boolean play) {
    System.out.println("Play again?(Y/N)");
    String Answer = console.next();
    if (Answer.equalsIgnoreCase("N")) {
        play = false;
    } else {
        play = true;
    }
    return play;

}
```

}